# Simple separation of SQL and business logic

Tags: sql, design-patterns, dao, business-logic

Facing limited options, what design pattern could be useful to separate SQL / database access from the business logic? Quite sadly I can‘t use fancy frameworks and have to design a simple solution by myself. The program only queries some tables, so the other CRUD-operations can be neglected. Furthermore joins e.g. are not necessary.

A super simplistic idea would be to put all SQL queries in different methods of a class, but this is probably not very elegant.

Searching, I found DAO or the Repository Pattern. As I understood, the general approach is to implement get(int id) and getAll() to let‘s say get one or all stored orders of a company. This would be very inefficient, if the programm let‘ say just needs to process all orders placed yesterday.

I would be very gateful for any advide.

Comment: A DAO is not limited to CRUD operations only. It can implement any search, update, insert, or delete operation. In your case you could define a DAO method called `findOrdersPlacedOn(Date placedOn):List<Order>`; and this method will implement a simple search by date.

Comment: what kind of operations do you have? You mentioned that the system is doing "only" queries, so what's the business logic doing here? Filtering?